# ETA infinity for download in full progress?

Tags: download, utorrent

How come the ETA for the highlighted uTorrent download is at infinity?

As you can see, the download is in full progress, size is 388 MB and almost 52% done. Its ETA should be in the order of 10 minutes...

[image]

Windows uTorrent version 3.3.29645, status icon in the bottom-right corner is green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O sorry, I just noticed clicking on the Info tab, that it has only .807 availability. That's probably the reason: there is no way to predict how long it's going to take with (only) this fraction available.

Right after posting my question the download speed for that torrent dropped to 0 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of X's there....

The ETA is based off a calculation of remaining bits to DL and your current rate, weighed against the time it took to obtain the bits already completed.  Thus, if a torrent had taken 10 years to get 95%, with a current speed of 100k/s, it would likely calculate out to infinity (shown for any amount of time greater than 2 years I believe).

One could stop the torrent, remove it (not deleting local files, of course) and then add it again in order to obtain a new estimation.  Just if case you deleted the .torrent file, uTorrent stores a working copy (you don't think good programers rely on users to keep such important things, do you?) in /users/"username"/appdata/roaming/utorrent/

Comment: LOL, also noticed the XX's :-) Busted!